# Writing time to subtitle text

Tags: ios, swift

I'm writing an app with swift like list app. When i create a new task everything is working fine but a want to write a creation time on Subtitle text of table view's cell. How can i do that?

Answer (score -1):

You can use `NSDate` to get the current date and time.

So in your creation method, (or object init):

```
let date = NSDate()
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter().Shortstyle
let dateString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)
```

Comment: Thank you for reply Cole but i know that, i don't need current date and time, i need to write row's creation time.

Comment: I found a solution as Objective-C in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7004280/sort-uitableview-core-data-via-nsdate thanks for advices